# linking error: undefined reference for architecture x86_64 for Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, qt

For the new OSX 10.9 and Xcode 5 / 5.01, I start to have a problem of linking error when using Qt (4.7), the error msg is like:

ld: '**......**' in ___.o contains undefined reference for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I double-checked many times and it seems my codes are all correct, and the project has been successfully built many many times before using lower version of XCode (and on other OSs as well).

After I checked many websites, there is no luck how to solve this problem.

So my question is: is there a way to figure out what is exactly the missing "undefined reference" complained by the linker?

Comment: I guess you are not linking in a library; please post the complete error message in order to help you find out which one it is.

Comment: It is the complete error msg actually, and that is why this error is confusing...

Comment: No, it's not.  I would like to see the symbols it cannot find.

Comment: Qt 4.7 (and 4.8) have major compatibility issues with 10.9.

Answer (score 2):

We have seen the same problem doing iOS development. For some it went away after turning off link time optimisation for all linked libraries. Make sure that all binary dependencies were built without them as well.

One way of finding the culprit is to list all undefined symbols in an .o file using `nm -u`. Then eliminating things from common and system libraries like NS* UI*. Then you look at what's left and try to deduce what can be missing.